# How to page through QueryResults

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am getting result from BigQuery using the following code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery

credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
scoped_credential = credential.with_scopes(BIG_QUERY_SCOPE)
client = bigquery.Client(project="XX-XX",credentials=scoped_credential)

query_results = client.run_sync_query(query_detail)
query_results.use_legacy_sql = False
query_results.run()

iterator = query_results.fetch_data()
rows = iterator.query_result.rows
```

But it only returns up-to 50000 rows. I tried to paginate while fetching data, but failed to figure out how to do it:

```
page_token = query_results.page_token
iterator = query_results.fetch_data(max_results=500, page_token=page_token)
```

I could not find out how to get the updated page_token.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close. Try running this code now:

```
data = list(query_results.fetch_data()) # changed from `iterator` to `data` the variable name
```

The management of page tokens is done automatically for you.